# Explain -> in PHP

Tags: php, syntax

I can't find any good videos or text that explains how the `->` works.
Like:

```
$bill -> wakeme();
```

Why not do:

```
wakeme($bill);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php - start there

Comment: You need to read about difference in 'procedural' style of programming and 'object oriented' style of programming. It's a langauge-agnostic topic, so you don't necessarily need to look for texts about PHP. PHP specific issueas are explained here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/oop5.intro.php

Comment: the php manual doesn't have enough details about the `arrow operator`. http://www.robert-gonzalez.com/2009/03/04/php-operators-double-and-single-arrow/

Comment: It's not an operator. Otherwise it would on operators list ;P

Answer (score 6):

`->` Is used in the OOP (Object Oriented Programming) in PHP so if you are working with classes you need to do this for example:

```
$myClass = new dog();
echo $myClass->getDogAge();
```

Try looking at the [Manual section on OOP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Answer (score 1):

Read this for starters: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php